# Javascript element .value not changing back the way I expected it to

Tags: php, javascript, function

I'm a long time visitor of the site but first time poster.

I am new to JavaScript and have done my best to make a script that will dynamically update a form based on a chosen parameter. When the user chooses a (in this case) part number they can click on an "update" button that will change seven other fields accordingly. In case there is a mistake, I have made a reset button that resets the part number field and (this is where it's broken) then if you click on the "update" button again, the other seven fields are suppose to reset as well. I hope that makes sense. About halfway through the list of part numbers I had tried the function and it worked great, but somewhere along the way it broke. Right now the only part that resets the way it should is the "oempma.value".

Anyways, sorry for the lengthy post, I'll get on with it. Here is my code for the form (new.php):

And here is the dynamicupdate.js file where the function is called from:

```
function dynamicupdate(form, prefix, part_number, flight_control, lat_position, long_position, vert_position, location, material, oempma) 
    {
        if(form)
            {
                if(part_number.value === "C6CF1124-1")
                    {
                    flight_control.value = "Aileron";
                    lat_position.value = "Left";
                    long_position.value = "Fwd";
                    vert_position.value = "N/A";
                    location.value = "Wing";
                    material.value = "Carbon Steel";                    
                }

                if(part_number.value === "C6CW1031-1")
                    {
                    flight_control.value = "Aileron";
                    lat_position.value = "";
                    long_position.value = "N/A";
                    vert_position.value = "";
                    location.value = "Wing";
                    material.value = "Carbon Steel";                    
                    }
                        if (part_number.value === "C6CW1031-1" && lat_position.value === "" && vert_position.value === "")
                        {
                        alert ("You must manually enter the \"Lat Position\" and \"Vert Position\" for this cable.");
                        }


            }

        else 
            {
            flight_control.value = "";
            lat_position.value = "";
            long_position.value = "";
            vert_position.value = "";
            location.value = "";
            material.value = "";
            }


        if(prefix.value === "PDM" || prefix.value === "TB" || prefix.value === "JNL")
            {
            oempma.value = "PMA";
            }
        else if(part_number.value === "")
            {
            oempma.value = "";
            }
        else
            {
            oempma.value = "OEM";
            }

        return;
    }
```

This function is also located in the dynamicupdate.js file, but for some reason I couldn't get it to stay in the code block above.

```
function resetsome(form, prefix, part_number)
    {
    part_number.value = "";
    prefix.value = "";
    }
```

I have tried troubleshooting this a few ways including removing some large blocks of the .js file back to where it use to work just in case I messed something up further along, but that didn't fix it. I've also done a lot of reading on the JavaScript language that applies to this situation, but I could see anything that I did wrong.

Comment: Could you provide a working example of the behaviour? For example a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Way too much code to expect us to go through. Can you strip it down to the minimum necessary to replicate the problem?

Comment: Agree - waaaaaaay too much code.

Comment: absolutely, sorry about that. I'll be right back with an edit...now, where's the sheepish smiley at.

Comment: i don't understand why reset just resets the two fields above it and then you need to press update to reset the values below it. Would it not make more sense for the reset button to reset *all* the fields?

Comment: @caitriona there are more fields before these ones that I'm trying to save the user from having to retype.

Comment: @AndrewFox but could the button not reset *all* the fields *after* it?

Comment: @caitriona I honestly didn't realize I could make a button to do that, but yes, that would work.

Comment: @caitriona I just reread your first comment. The update button is there so when you choose a part number it automatically fills in the rest of the fields, not to reset anything.

Comment: @Zeta I went to jsfiddle as you suggested, what a cool site! Here is the link to my fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/FoxRocks/uLebs/3/)

Comment: @Zeta I'm not sure why, but my fiddle doesn't work at all even though I essentially copied and pasted it right from my notepad. I have been provided with a solution, so there is no need to waste your time looking at the fiddle, I just wanted to mention it just in case. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is this:

```
if(form){/*...*/}
```

The code that resets the fields will not be executed when form is true.

Try this:

```
 function dynamicupdate(form, prefix, part_number, flight_control, lat_position, long_position, vert_position, location, material, oempma) 
    {
      if(!form)return;


        if(part_number.value !== ""){
                if(part_number.value === "C6CF1124-1")
                    {
                    flight_control.value = "Aileron";
                    lat_position.value = "Left";
                    long_position.value = "Fwd";
                    vert_position.value = "N/A";
                    location.value = "Wing";
                    material.value = "Carbon Steel";                    
                }

                if(part_number.value === "C6CW1031-1")
                    {
                    flight_control.value = "Aileron";
                    lat_position.value = "";
                    long_position.value = "N/A";
                    vert_position.value = "";
                    location.value = "Wing";
                    material.value = "Carbon Steel";                    
                    }
                        if (part_number.value === "C6CW1031-1" && lat_position.value === "" && vert_position.value === "")
                        {
                        alert ("You must manually enter the \"Lat Position\" and \"Vert Position\" for this cable.");
                        }


            }

        else {//when part_number.value is empty reset the fields
            flight_control.value = "";
            lat_position.value = "";
            long_position.value = "";
            vert_position.value = "";
            location.value = "";
            material.value = "";
            }


        if(prefix.value === "PDM" || prefix.value === "TB" || prefix.value === "JNL")
            {
            oempma.value = "PMA";
            }
        else if(part_number.value === "")
            {
            oempma.value = "";
            }
        else
            {
            oempma.value = "OEM";
            }

        return;
    }
```

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested and everything works just great! I understand the 'if(part_number.value !== "")' bit, that makes perfect sense to me. But can you tell me about the 'if(!form) return;' part? I am guessing it means that if there is no form to process, just exit (or return). Is that right? Thank you for your time in providing me with a solution :)

Comment: I cant tell you exactly, for what `if(!form)` is good for. In your original code you have `if(form)` , the codeblock will only be executed when form is true, so there must be some cases where form may be false. Now the function will be leaved immediately, when form is false.

Comment: hmmm, food for thought I guess. Thanks for the follow up!

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of problems with your code, and no, I'm not thinking about length or code structure.

First of all, if you don't need some parameters, you should not define them in the function, if you define them, you should use them, your form parameter in the `resetsome` function is unused and it should be deleted or used.

Secondly, the value of `this` is the object (function) where you are in. For instance, try this:

```
this.foo = 'bar';
function that()
{
    this.foo = 'loremipsum';
}
that();
alert(this.foo);
```

and you will know what I mean.

Instead of using the members of this you should create variables and store your values there. I believe if you do that your code should work.

Comment: I just deleted the "form" parameter from my resetsome function and my reset stopped working.

Comment: Probably you still pass the form parameter in your onclick event.

Comment: you are correct, I forgot to remove it from my onclick event. Thanks :)
Although I have ultimately chosen the above solution, I appreciate your suggestion and for taking the time to reply. Thanks!